# Turn on double spacing between gb4e lines

Tags: spacing, linguistics, vertical-spacing, setspace, gb4e

I need to set double spacing between the lines of linguistic examples. The command `\doublespacing` works for the regular paragraphs, but not inside `exe` environments. Below, I give a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing 

\lipsum[4]

\begin{exe}
    \ex \glll qwertyui qwewer \\
    gloss gloss x \\
    bla blaaaaa bla \\
\end{exe}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The output of the above is this:
[image: no double spacing between lines of a linguistic example]

Whereas what I am looking for is something like this:
[image: the desired double space in a linguistic example]

I will be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue `\nosinglegloss` in the document preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\nosinglegloss

\begin{document}

\doublespacing 

\lipsum[4]

\begin{exe}
    \ex \glll qwertyui qwewer \\
    gloss gloss x \\
    bla blaaaaa bla \\
\end{exe}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!